# Prices are showing as zeros in product page

Tags: magento2, products, product-page, frontend-error, product-prices

I have a problem with product prices, the prices in the backend are right
and on the home page and search list as well.
But in the product page they turn to be zero after a second of the page load
Also when I add a product to the cart the total amount is zero
I don't  where the issue is and how to fix it.
Any ideas please!
[image]
[image]

Comment: you need to debug pdp page,

Comment: if you can hit debugger on pdp page, you will know the answer

Comment: could you explain more what is pdp page and how can I debug it?

Comment: that template file which is rendering this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem in Magento 2 Version, Upgrade it to latest Magento Version and it will resolve this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked !!!